# Google Maps geocoding differences

Tags: google-maps, google-geocoding-api

I looked throught the answers section and although many are similar none of them address this problem directly.

I have and address that is geocoded in the web page thus:

```
var lat = '';
var lng = '';
var address = '3100 Ray Ferrero Jr Blvd Fort Lauderdale, FL 33314';
geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
  if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) { then I display the map }
```

This gives an approximate location but it is wrong.

I also have a link to the full size google map using the same address

https://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&hl=en&q=3100+Ray+Ferrero+Jr+Blvd,+Fort+Lauderdale+FL+33314

This maps the location correctly (using the same address as the web page).

The only thing I can find that is strange is that this street does not seem to exist on either map and is part of a campus. How can the full page map link directly to this address and the web page embedded version cannot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Maps uses many different sources for their data, the geocoder is only one.  The Places API is another.

That location is not (currently) in the geocoder.  It is in the [Places API database](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_example_geo2.asp?addr1=3100%20Ray%20Ferrero%20Jr%20Blvd,%20Fort%20Lauderdale%20FL%2033314&place=1).

Comment: Thanks for that information. Any idea why google returns an "OK" on geocode when it really can't geocode that location?

Comment: It will return OK if it can return any match for the string.  There is data in the results for the accuracy and type of the result, as well as other information that can be used to evaluate its suitability (like the formatted address).